# How find this limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^{-2x}(\cos{x}+2\sin x)+e^{-x^2}(\sin{x})^2}{e^{-x}(\cos{x}+\sin{x})}$

Tags: limits

Find this limit.

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-2x}(\cos{x}+2\sin x)+e^{-x^2}(\sin{x})^2}{e^{-x}(\cos{x}+\sin{x})}$$

This wolf can't have reslut. [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bx%5Cto%2B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cdfrac%7Be%5E%7B-2x%7D%28cosx%2B2sinx%29%2Be%5E%7B-x%5E2%7D%28sinx%29%5E2%7D%7Be%5E%7B-x%7D%28cosx%2Bsinx%29%7D&dataset=)

maybe this limit is not exsit? so how prove it? 
Thank you

Comment: @nanchangjian. Before we even attempt to do this problem, how many vertical asymptotes does this graph have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are arbitrarily large $x$ at which our function is not even defined. And by taking $x$ close enough to $2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}$, we can make our function arbitrarily large positive or negative.

Comment: why? can you explain? Thank you

Comment: When $x=2n\pi +\frac{3\pi}{4}$, we have $\cos x+\sin x=0$.

Comment: @nanchangjian Why don't you look at the stuff more closely yourself? Once the OP has pointed you to the problem that the function may be undefined at some points, this is direct, no?

Comment: You are welcome. There are "bad points" at and near $2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $2n\pi +\frac{7\pi}{4}$.